# Boost.Python cannot create 'Boost.Python.class' instances

Tags: python, c++, boost

I'm trying to find out in Boost.Python, and I can't wrap any class. I can create `.pyd` that will keep function, but when I create this with class, I get this:

```
TypeError: cannot create 'Boost.Python.class' instances.
```

So I have 3 files: `myPoint.h`, `myPoint.cpp`, `classPoint.cpp`. What am I doing wrong?

**myPoint.h**

```
struct myPoint {
    int x, y;
    myPoint(int _x, int _y);
};
```

**myPoint.cpp**

```
#include "myPoint.h"
myPoint::myPoint(int _x, int _y): x(_x), y(_y) {}
```

**classPoint.cpp**

```
#define BOOST_PYTHON_STATIC_LIB

#include <boost\python.hpp>
#include "myPoint.h"

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(classPoint) {
    using namespace boost::python;
    class_<myPoint>("myPoint", init<int, int>());
}
```